# An easy way to disable right click on Lubuntu 16.04 toolbar

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, mouse, lxpanel

I'm in the process of setting up a public access station for the folks where I live and I need to lock it down as much as I can to prevent tampering and inappropriate activity. Kind of like a semi-kiosk mode. I've been able to accomplish some of this but I need assistance in disabling right clicking on Lubuntu's toolbar (LXPanel, I believe it's called,) to prevent users from adding or deleting certain applets, such as the clock or network manager. Is there an easy of doing this that someone can show me step by step?

Also, is there a way to prevent users from changing entries or settings in the network manager without having to delete the applet?

I would appreciate any assistance that will help me accomplish these tasks! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the trouble and either

- run Chrome / Firefox in kioskmode if this is the only app you want to make available (you can do anything with browser based cloud apps right?)
- switch to a more sophisticated desktop environment which supports "kiosk mode" natively and set it up properly:

  - **XFCE - Xubuntu**
    https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/kiosk_mode
  - **KDE - Kubuntu**
    [https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Kiosk/Introduction](https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/kiosk_mode)
- or schedule an hourly/daily/weekly automated snapshot restore, which puts the lxde environment back in it's original state.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, for your answer. However, the first two options, although good ones, are not practical for my hardware/situation, partly because I've already put a lot of work into my current install. The third one might be an option, although I would prefer to see if there's a way to disable right clicking.